# Finding the general solution to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone know how I would go about answering this question? Thank you.

(a) Find the general solution to the linear system Ax = b, expressing your answer in the form of a vector plus a subspace.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7pe97N8.png]

Comment: Well, what methods have you been taught for solving linear systems?

Answer (score 0):

Using Gaussian Elimination method you can solve this linear system. See this [examples](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m23s06/public_html/handouts/row_reduction_examples.pdf), they are really simple and I hope you can read it by yourself. If you have any confusion let me know.